# Opsworks integration with hipchat doesn't work

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am trying to integrate AWS Opsworks with Hipchat using this cookbook:
https://github.com/wzin/opsworks_hipchat

I have created a new repo in Bitbucket in which I have a Berksfile.
Berksfile content:
cookbook 'opsworks_hipchat', git: https://github.com/wzin/opsworks_hipchat.git

On Stack Setings I have :

```
Manage Berkshelfyes
Berkshelf version3.2.0
```

...but when I try to run Setup I get the following error:

```
[2015-09-15T20:32:34+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found:
   Object not found: /reports/nodes/php-app1.localdomain/runs
[2015-09-15T20:32:34+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 412 Precondition Failed:
   No such cookbook: opsworks_hipchat
```

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1) Did you specify the cookbook as a custom cookbook in opsworks? (Stack Settings -> Repository URL)

2) Did you update the cookbooks on the machine you are trying to setup this on? (Stack -> Run Command -> Pick "Update Custom Cookbooks" from Command drop down -> select machines (all probably) -> Click Update Custom Cookbooks button.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on Berksfile and I created my own repo containing that cookbook. And it worked.